# Intercept all emails sent from Xampp Mercury Mail Server

Tags: email, xampp, mail-server

I have a Xampp Server that I use only in a development environment. In order to preview emails that would be sent from the live sites without actually sending them I would like to intercept all the emails sent from this server. I would like to be able to either send them all to a specific email or save them as files instead of sending them to whatever address they're set to go to. This way I can make sure they are correct without accidently sending emails during testing.

I found a similar question with an answer
[here](https://superuser.com/questions/612317/catch-all-outgoing-email-in-mercury)
but was unable to find a way to open any of the dialogs in the answer and so it didn't get me very far.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the sendmail configuration within your php.ini.

Create a file named `smtp_catcher.php` and the set the `sendmail_path`

```
sendmail_path = "php C:\path\to\file\smtp_catcher.php"
```

Then in your `smtp_catcher.php` add this block:

```
#!/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
<?php

# create a filename for the emlx file
list($ms, $time) = explode(' ', microtime());
$filename = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.date('Y-m-d h.i.s,', $time).substr($ms,2,3).'.emlx';

# write the email contents to the file
$email_contents = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$fstat = fstat($email_contents);
file_put_contents($filename, $fstat['size']."\n");
file_put_contents($filename, $email_contents, FILE_APPEND);

# open up the emlx file (using Apple Mail)
exec('open '.escapeshellarg($filename));

?>
```

Now I am not sure what extension you'll need to use to view the emails but this should catch all emails going out.

**NOTE:** make sure that php is in your window's environment PATH

Comment: Note that if php is not in our window's environment Path you may need to restart your computer after adding it before this will work.